# JQuery toggle button first two clicks don't work as intended

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, google-sites

My html code is fairly simple, I want to have a (show/hide) button that when pressed scrolls down the abstract of the paper, and when pressed again scrolls it back up. I use JQuery 1.5 inside an HTML box on a google site. 
The first line of the html box is

Then the html:

The last part of the html box is the following script:

```js
$("#abstract1").click(function () {
    $("abstract1").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js"></script>

<div><font color="#3d85c6"><b>Working Papers</b></font></div>
    
<div><b><font color="#0b5394"><a>Paper 1</a>
&nbsp;</font></b><button id="abstract1"><b>Abstract</b></button><br/> </div>
<abstract1 style="display:none">
<div style="line-height:175%;margin-bottom:1em"><font size="2"><font size="2">
blah blah blah...
&nbsp;</font></font></div>
</abstract1>
```

As one that doesn't really know html, I was pretty amazed this works :) The only issue is that on the first click the abstract appears immediately (doesn't slide), and on the second click it appears scrolling down (after it was already visible). Then it works perfectly, scrolling down and up...

What did I do wrong?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: There are a few issues with your HTML. First of all, `<abstract1>` is not a valid element and `<font>` is deprecated (if you are using HTML5). And I would put the inline CSS styling into a separate CSS file or style tag. Here's how I would lay out your markup: https://jsfiddle.net/jjnmdg1n/1/ :o)

Comment: In the JSFiddle linked above the sliding works as it's supposed to. One reason can be that it's running in a different environment. But invalid markup can cause misbehavior like what you explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You appear to have invalid tags such as `<abstract1>` and tend to double up on tags. In the below code snippet I've changed your `<abstract1>` tags to `<div>` tags and applied the class of `abstract1` to it, allowing you to target the div class by using the selector `.abstract1` in your javascript code.

I've also 'cleaned' up your code a little so it uses more appropriate HTML tags (and removed those that were unnecessary).

See the code snippet below for a working example:

```js
$("#abstract1").click(function () {
    $(".abstract1").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <font color="#3d85c6"><b>Working Papers</b></font>
</div>
    
<div>
  <b><font color="#0b5394"><a>Paper 1</a>&nbsp;</font></b>
  <button id="abstract1"><b>Abstract</b></button><br /> 
</div>

<!-- Here is where you need to change the <abstract1> tag to this div: -->
<div class="abstract1" style="display:none">
  <span style="line-height:175%;margin-bottom:1em">
    <font size="2">blah blah blah...&nbsp;</font>
  </span>
</div>
```